# IoTBrowser, navigate webview from task/thread

Tags: c#, .net, azure, win-universal-app

There's a webview:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Margin="0,10" Grid.RowSpan="3" LoadCompleted="webView_LoadCompleted"/>
```

And there's a basic snippet of code, which starts a task that will listen to an azure device. Some code is missing from the below example, presume the device was created normally.

The problem, is that I'd like to tell the Webview to navigate to a certain webpage, depending on the content of the received message.

The problem is,. "Window.Current" is null, so it crashes.

```
public App()
{
  Task.Run(ReceiveC2dAsync);
}

private async static Task ReceiveC2dAsync()
{
  while (true)
  {
    Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
    if(receivedMessage != null)
    {
      // Snip
      Task.Run(Navigate);
    }
  }
}

private async static Task Navigate()
{
  try
  {
    if(Window.Current.Content != null)
      ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "http://www.google.com");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
  }
}
```

In the override code:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
```

The following code can be used to navigate to a desired website when the application launches:

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
if(rootFrame == null) rootFrame = new Frame();
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "ms-appx-web:///help.html");
```

So, current is not null at this point.
If i save rootframe as a static, and use it at a later point in the task, I get a marshal error - basically stating the object is referenced to be marshaled to another thread.

My C# knowledge is,. in progress I fear.
So far I've been unable to find a proper explanation on how to have the webview respond to the internal task. Is it possible? And if so, how?

PS: The initial sample code is from: https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/IoTBrowser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem, is that I'd like to tell the Webview to navigate to a certain webpage

According to your code snippet, you are developing a UWP app. If you want to know how [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) navigate to a web site, you should be able to use `Navigate` method of `WebView`, for example:

```
webView.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

> The following code can be used to navigate to a desired website when the application launches:

The code snippet by default inside [`OnLaunched`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_OnLaunched_Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_LaunchActivatedEventArgs_) navigate to one page by  [`Frame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame).  `Frame` control supports navigation to [`Page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page) instances, not web pages, you cannot navigate to a website by `Frame`. Your above code snippet can only let the `rootFrame` navigate to `MainPage`, not the `help.html`. But you can  get the `ms-appx-web:///help.html` parameter on `MainPage` and navigate to it by a `WebView` on `MainPage`.

> I get a marshal error - basically stating the object is referenced to be marshaled to another thread.

If you want to invoke `UIElement` in a different thread, you should be able to use [`Core​Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher), cannot invoke directly.

For a conclusion, I think what you actually want to do is navigate to a web site by `WebView` from a non UI thread. For example:

```
await Task.Run(Navigate);
private async Task Navigate()
{        
    try
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            webView.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));    
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aye, the last one is close to the desired functionality. However, shouldn't that be: ""await System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RunAsync"" - which results in an error stating "RunAsync" doest not exist in that namespace. Which uses should be included for this, or is this function unavailable in UWP?

Comment: @Thomas, no, its type is  `Windows.UI.Core.Core​Dispatcher`. I updated my code snippet to add complete reference please check.

Comment: Got it, that works. I did have to save a reference to the webview during OnLaunched however (Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame; mainWindow = rootFrame), as "webView" is unavailable in the Navigate function. But it's navigating as expected now, so will mark your solution as accepted right away - as your solution was on the mark.